# How to wait for onValue to return value from Firebase Realtime Database in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a **getData** function witha **onValue** function from Firebase. But when I call it, it does not wait for the **onValue** to finish, with the consequence of giving **undefined** back.

Here is the **getData** function:

```
function getData(path) {
    try {
        const reference = ref(database, path);
        onValue(reference, (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            return data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
            return undefined;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return undefined;
    }
    console.log('END!');
}
```

and when I call the function, the console looks like this:

```
END!
DATA: *[correct data]*
```

I already tried to make it a variable instead of a function.
Does someone know how I can make it wait for **onValue** to finish.

Comment: There is a builtin [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#get) method that does what you want. You might also find the docs on [Promise chaining](https://web.dev/promises/#chaining) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only get a value once, you should use `get()` instead of `onValue`.

```
function getData(path) {
    try {
        const reference = ref(database, path);
        return get(reference).((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            console.log('DATA: ' + data);
            return data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
            return undefined;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return undefined;
    }
    console.log('END!');
}
```

All the logging makes the function quite a lot more complex than needed, so distilled to its essence this is:

```
function getData(path) {
    const reference = ref(database, path);
    return get(reference).((snapshot) => snaphot.val());
}
```